# Issue on my MBP 2012

Tags: gnome, reboot, 16.10

I have a little issue this morning when I rebooted my MBP 2012. In reality, I got rid of OSX to Ubuntu, and when I rebooted my MBP, the following image appears. Could anyone be able to tell me what do I have to do to retrieve my OS without losing anything? I know I could use cmd + R, but I will lose everything.

[image]

Comment: Could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I have to much characters Boot-info.txt. If you want, I could send you that information by email or something like that.

Comment: I'll try soon the boot-repair (and also put that Boot-info.txt), because I got the following line `=================== Suggested repair
The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of sdb2, using the following options:        sdb1/boot/efi,
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s    use-standard-efi-file rename-ms-efi`

Comment: That's uplifting insofar as Boot-Info thinks it might be able to fix the boot issue. You can go ahead and ask Boot-Repair to perform those repairs if you want. If that fixes the issue please say so. If not, for a more thorough analysis we'll need to take a look at the full Boot-Info log.

Comment: @DavidFoerster You helped me for a lot of things today. All of them worked perfectly. I want to thank you again for your work, it is very appreciated.